# Dynamic tables in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dynamic-tables

I followed the below link to understand the concept of dynamic tables

https://www.snowflake.com/blog/dynamic-tables-delivering-declarative-streaming-data-pipelines/

I got a question while going through the link. I understood that even if it is polling, warehouse compute cost will not be incurred if there is no incremental data to process. But are we also not going to spend any cloud service credits due to the polling mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

The blog post you linked to says that this feature is in "private preview".

While features are in private preview, pricing has not been decided and documentation has not been released either.

For a definitive answer to this question you'll need to wait until the feature is in public preview and/or GA.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic Tables would occur 3 types of cost -

```
Storage Cost - on a flat rate per TB
Cloud Services Compute - for triggering refreshes when an underlying base object has changed.(This is subject to Cloud Services cost being greater than 10% of the daily warehouse cost for the account.)
Virtual Warehouse compute - to run queries against base object when they are initially populated, and later, when they are continuously refreshed.
```

It will be more clear once the feature is in Public Preview in Snowflake.